# Embedding item in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I need to embed an item in javascript side. When I try this on normal html file, it works normally. When I try to append this item in javascript side it doesn't work. I try to create a chrome extension, so I need to do this inside content.js.
Problematic item is this one:

< div id='rg_em bed_link_4 763580' class='rg_em bed_link' data-so ng-id='47 63580' >Read < a hr ef='https://genius.com/Muslum-gurses-hasret-ruzgarlar-lyrics'>“Hasret Rüzgarları” by Müslüm Gürses on Genius< / div> < scr ipt crossorigin src='//genius.com/songs/4763580/embed.js'></sc ript >

It only shows me link but doesn't show me what's embedded. Is there a way to fix this?

```
const container = document.createElement("div");
    const accordionItemHTML = `
    <head>
        <style>
            /* Add some basic styling for the accordion */
            .accordion {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                max-width: 300px;
            }
    
            .accordion-item {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                border-radius: 5px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            .accordion-button {
                background-color: #ddd;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: left;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    
            .accordion-content {
                display: none;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-button" id="section1Container">See lyrics</div>
        <div class="accordion-content" id="section1">
        <div id='rg_embed_link_4763580' class='rg_embed_link' data-song-id='4763580'>Read <a href='https://genius.com/Muslum-gurses-hasret-ruzgarlar-lyrics'>“Hasret Rüzgarları” by Müslüm Gürses</a> on Genius</div> <script crossorigin src='//genius.com/songs/4763580/embed.js'></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
         `;
    container.innerHTML = accordionItemHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    const section1Container = document.getElementById("section1Container");
    
    section1Container.addEventListener("click", function () {
      const content = document.getElementById("section1");
      content.style.display = content.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
    });
```

Comment: `<script>` tags are ignored inside innerHTML. You'll need to add it via createElement+appendChild explicitly.